# difference between a VPS and linux-vserver

Tags: vps, linux-vserver

So i'd like to know what is more exactly a Vserver and if in terms of performance can be compared with a VPS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an apples-to-flamethrowers comparison.  A VPS is a pricing/service delivery model.  A VServer is a particular way of delivering a VPS; other options include paravirtualization (like Xen) or whole-system virtualization.  Indeed, the linux-vserver project even [refers to itself as a method of creating a VPS](http://linux-vserver.org/Overview#Abstract).

Answer (score -2):

It depends. The perceived performance inside your VM depends on the host hardware, the load of the other VMs running on the host, the virtualization software and the virtualization type. vserver should have better performance than a VPS on the same host and running the same VMs.

See: http://linux-vserver.org/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Performance.3F